# How to prevent verbatim from generating linebreak?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I tried:

```
\begin{verbatim} is_terminating() \end{verbatim} function can be implemented as follows:
```

But the text after verbatim section will be printed in a next line, is there a way to prevent this happen? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know of `\verb|is_terminating()|` for inline verbatim?

Comment: @Werner Grundlingh: Thank you sir! That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using inline verbatim: `\verb|is_terminating()|`. For some discussion on the different verbatim environments, read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Verbatim_Text).

The [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) also provides a form of inline verbatim through its inline code macro `\lstinline`. It works uses the same interface as inline verbatim with delimiters defining the inline code range: `\lstinline!is_terminating()!`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `\verb` command instead. The first character after `\verb` acts as delimiter, *"such that all text up to the next occurence of that character is printed literally. This character may not appear in the literal text, obviously."* (Kopka and Daly, *Guide to LaTeX*)

```
\verb|is_terminating()| function can be implemented as follows:
```